# How can I find out the dependencies and build rule used to build something in scons

Tags: scons

I don't want to use scons --n, I want to see how something *was* built, not how it would be built now.

I presume its possible to use .sconsdblite somehow.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2):

The [SCons man pages](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) explains the `--tree` command line options that can be used to display the targets' dependency info.

The most basic way to use it is as follows:

```
# scons --tree=all
```

There are several different tree options explained therein, depending on your situation.

Additionally there are several `--debug` options available.

This might help do what you mention in your comments: `--debug=explain`

```
Print an explanation of precisely why scons is deciding to (re-)build 
any targets. (Note: this does not print anything for targets that are
not rebuilt.)
```

Comment: -tree requires it to build the tree first. I don't want the tree to be rebuilt. I want to know how something *was* built, rather than how it *will be* built

Comment: @TomTanner, I think the `--tree` output will be the same before and after a target is built. Are you trying to determine what was the dependency that changed and caused a particular target to be rebuilt? Im not sure if that can be done for something built in the past, but you can use this: `--debug=explain`

Comment: it's not just the --tree output. I want the command used to build. I'm trying to compare scons with the build system we currently use that has a method for listing all this stuff on a built object.

Comment: @TomTanner, Ok, I didnt understand it that way from the question. So for a particular entity built with SCons, you want to see the compiler (and os) command(s) that ***were*** issued? I dont know if that info is stored anywhere. I did a google search earlier on the .sconsdblite and I didnt see anything useful. You might consider asking a question on the scons user alias: users@scons.tigris.org

Comment: @TomTanner, BTW, what is the build system and method used for listing this stuff on a built object? It may just be a simple case of adding some sort of a logger.

Comment: the old build system is clearmake. it logs everything. scons must log this information as it knows if the build action has changed.

Comment: @TomTanner, good point, Ive seen SCons rebuild just because I changed the compilation flags. Unfortunately I havent seen anything to be able to dump that info. They're talking on the SCons mailing lists of preparing for another release soon, that would be a good feature request. Let me know if you want to submit it, as Im considering helping out with the next release. StackOverflow is asking me if I want to move this to a chat... would that be helpfull?